# как отсортировать вывод print?

Tags: python

Есть простейший пример с рекурсивной функцией:

```
def rec(x):
    if x == 0:
        return
    else:
        print(x, 'Some Text')
        rec(x - 1)

rec(5)
```

которая выводит

```
5 Some Text
4 Some Text
3 Some Text
2 Some Text
1 Some Text
```

Подскажите, как отсортировать вывод х в возрастающем порядке.

Comment: поменяйте местами вызов print и rec(x-1)

Comment: @godva большое спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: @godva почему это работает? Я даже через визуалайзер пропустил и все-равно не понял. До всяких принтов функция рекурсивно вызывается от всё меньшего числа, когда доходит до нуля - делает пустой return. Почему она продолжает печатать значения?

Comment: @whizz169, когда x дойдет до нуля вызовется return и будет возврат в функцию rec(1) (которая вызвала rec(0)), в которой выполнится print и  вернется в rec(2) где снова print и так далее.

Comment: @godva спасибо, вроде понял) всегда рекурсия была больной темой для меня